# Call a CXF Client through a Java Bean with Mule

Tags: mule, cxf, mule-flow

Im trying to consume this webservice: http://wsf.cdyne.com/WeatherWS/Weather.asmx?wsdl from another wsdl... Dont worry for that, im just tryng to make some kind of bridge to test the webservice call with not logic at all, so, the flow that i need is something like that

cxf:jaxws-service --- > Java bean ----> externalWebservice

The problem is that i cant find how to call through my java impl class the external webservice, i need to inject that in my bean but i cant find how to do it. ACtualy my flow is this:

```
    <flow name="soapservice" doc:name="soapservice">
        <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response"
            address="http://localhost:60603/Hello" doc:name="HTTP" />
        <cxf:jaxws-service serviceClass="org.example.HelloWorld"
            doc:name="SOAP" />
        <component class="org.example.HelloWorldImpl" doc:name="Java" />
    </flow>
```

Everything works fine, the service returns the entry parameter, but i need to retrieve some data from the Weather Webservice.
Somebody can help me to consume that webservice with CXF?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this, the best is to create another `flow` with a `request-response` VM inbound and a CXF client to consume the remote web service. The following explains how to generate the CXF client: http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Consuming+Web+Services+with+CXF

Then you can inject this other `flow` in your `component` via Component Bindings (see: http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Component+Bindings). That way `org.example.HelloWorldImpl` will have the possibility to call the remote web service via an interface call that behind the scene calls a flow that performs the CXF client interaction.

So in your case, assuming:

- the CXF-generated service interface is `com.cdyne.wsf.WeatherWS`,
- the method you're interested in is `getCityWeatherByZip`,
- the CXF-generate service client is `com.cdyne.wsf.WeatherWS_Service`,
- the `org.example.HelloWorld` class can receive an instance of `com.cdyne.wsf.WeatherWS` by injection

you would have something *similar* to:

```
<flow name="soapservice">
    <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response"
        address="http://localhost:60603/Hello" />
    <cxf:jaxws-service serviceClass="org.example.HelloWorld" />
    <component class="org.example.HelloWorldImpl">
        <binding interface="com.cdyne.wsf.WeatherWS"
            method="getCityWeatherByZip">
            <vm:outbound-endpoint path="callGetCityWeatherByZip"
                exchange-pattern="request-response" />
        </binding>
    </component>
</flow>

<flow name="getCityWeatherByZip">
    <vm:inbound-endpoint path="callGetCityWeatherByZip"
        exchange-pattern="request-response" />

    <cxf:jaxws-client
        clientClass="com.cdyne.wsf.WeatherWS_Service"
        port="WeatherSoap" operation="GetCityWeatherByZip" />

    <http:outbound-endpoint
        address="http://wsf.cdyne.com/WeatherWS/Weather.asmx"
        exchange-pattern="request-response" />
</flow>
```

Comment: Thaks for answer! Very usefull to understand a little more this, my problem is that i cant find how to make the binding with this new cxf client that you name. If you can help me showing some code would be great. Thanks in advance =)

Comment: Another question (the last one) . Mule says that vm:outbound-endpoint cannot be child of the element Binding. Thats right?

Comment: I don't have this issue. Is it something you see in your XML editor or an exception thrown at start-up? If the former and Mule starts: just ignore it.

Comment: The editor throw that error, and nothings happens when i try to deploy the service. But i thing that is related with other stuff. Now its my turn to code. Thanks again!

Comment: Don't hesitate to ask another question if you hit further issues. Though with a different test web service, I've validated my answer first before posting it so it should work for you. It was on Mule 3.3.1 but it should work the same on 3.4.0.

Comment: I use Mule 3.4.0 and trying to deploy your code i get a java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.cdyne.wsf.WeatherWS ... So i replace the class definition in the binding for com.cdyne.ws.weatherws.WeatherSoap ... 
After that, says that cant find the class com.cdyne.wsf.WeatherWS_Service so, i change the clientClass in the jaxws-client for com.cdyne.ws.weatherws.Weather. After that everything looks nice, so i try to deploy again... And now shows the next error:

javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: Port {http://ws.cdyne.com/WeatherWS/}WeatherSoap not found.

Sorry for insist, but im really lost

Comment: As it said in my answer, I have made assumptions on the class / interface names generated by CXF: you have to use the right ones based on the CXF generation and however you may have configured it. Same for `port`: you have to use the right values for your example, I've just shown you a working approach for interacting with a CXF client through component binding but I haven't done it for your particular case. That's your job :)

Comment: If you want better help, open another question with the state of your flows, the hand-crafted and generated Java code. This will help helping you.